# flaskを用いてWordNetで得られる文字列を送ることができない

Tags: python, flask

現在, WordNetで得た上位語を用いるためにflaskを使っています.
LocalhostにgetSynLinkRecursive関数で得られる''.join(getWord(sense.wordid).lemma)をreturnでLocalhostに送りたいです.
現在のコードだと一度, getSynLinkRecursiveをtekitoという関数で呼び出しそこで得られた配列をaという配列に格納してからその値をホストに送ろうと考えています. しかしこのaをprintで確認するとNoneとなってしまいます.
a配列にどのように文字を格納していけば良いか教えてください.
よろしくお願いいたします.

以下が, 関連のありそうなソースコードになります.

```
def getSynLinksRecursive(senses,link='hype', lang='jpn', _depth=0):
  y=[]
  x=[]
  for sense in senses:
    synLinks = getSynLinks(sense, link)
    if synLinks:
      y.append(''.join(getWord(sense.wordid).lemma))
    _senses = []
    for synLink in synLinks:
      sense = getSense(synLink.synset2, lang)
      if sense:
        _senses.append(sense)
    getSynLinksRecursive(_senses,link, lang, _depth+1)
  if _depth == 1:
    x.append(y)
    #print(",".join([str(j) for j in x]))
    return ",".join([str(j) for j in x])

#@app.route('/')
def tekito():
    a=[]
    words = getWords('りんご')
    senses = getSenses(words[0])
    link = 'hype'
    lang = 'jpn'
    a = getSynLinksRecursive(senses,link, lang)
    print(a)
    #print(",".join([str(i) for i in a]))
    #return ",".join(a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  conn = sqlite3.connect("wnjpn.db",check_same_thread = False)
  tekito()
　app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

`getSynLinksRecursive`を`_depth`なしで呼び出した時に、値を返していないので`None`になりますね。
`getSynLinksRecursive`を直せばいいかと思います。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます._depthを指定して

Comment: 0を代入したところNoneではなくりんごを取得することができました. しかし, ＿depthの値が異なるりんごの上位語、果物などの値が取得できませんでした.(例えば, _depthの値を2などに変更しても得られる値はりんごのみでした.)
getSynLinksRecursive内の
if synLinks:
      y.append(''.join(getWord(sense.wordid).lemma))
コード部分をいかに書き換えると正しくprintすることはできました.
print ''.join([' '*2*_depth,
                     getWord(sense.wordid).lemma,
                     ' ',
                     getSynset(sense.synset).name])

returnの返し方が間違っているんでしょうか.

Comment: getSynLinksRecursive がどういう動作をする（ことを期待している）のか、日本語で説明できますか?

Comment: 引数の値を取得し, synLinks = getSynLinks(sense, link)でsensesに関するsynLinksを取得." ''.join(getWord(sense.wordid).lemmaでsensesの上位語をyに格納していく処理だとおもいます. 
期待としては,　_depthの値が変わったときのgetWord(sense.wordid).lemmaをyに格納しreturnで返す処理ができることです.

Comment: ごめんなさい。自分が書こうとしているコードがどういう動作をするのかを聞かれて、「だと思います」と答えているようでは直せなくて当たり前だと思います。コードの名前や構造から考えて、ある語のシノニムを再帰的に探索して列挙する機能だということは想像できます。しかし、探索については (1)とにかく全て探索しつくす (2)ある回数分探索したら探索をやめる、返し方については、(1)見つかったものを返す (2)見つかったものとそこに行き着くまでの道のりを返す ぐらいのバリエーションは容易に思いつきます。ただ、今はとにかくまともに値を返していないので、本当はどうしたいのかの推測はできません。

Comment: とにかくコードが不完全なのでこれは一体なにをしたいんだ? というのが分からないのです。（ある語のシノニムを再帰的‌​に探索して列挙する、ということまでは推測できても）

Comment: あーでもなんとなく、2階層分掘り進んで（つまり、「シノニム」と「シノニムのシノニム」までの）リストを作りたい関数のように見えてきました。それで合っていますか?

Comment: ありがとうございます. 2階層分を掘り進んでリストに取り入れる関数にしたいと考えています. コードに関しては自分でも読んでもう少し理解を深めます. 大変失礼いたしました.